# series of integrals Mathematica Wolfram

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, mathematica

Does somebody knows how to represent series of integrals in Mathematica? I would like to represent something like $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^{2n}xdx$ and prove convergence of it, but after searching docs, it only shows some very simple discrete sums

Comment: You can check the [$\texttt{Mathematica}$ Wolfram Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html).

Comment: Is this the question, then:  Suppose I have functions $f_n$ so that Mathematica  does not evaluate $\int f_n$ in closed form.  Can I compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n$ in Mathematica anyway?  I guess we need to know: can Wolfram recognize when $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n=\int \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n$ is valid?

Answer (score 3):

If you simply plug that integral into Mathematica, it will give

```
Integrate[Tan[x]^(2n),{x,0,Pi/4}] = (PolyGamma[0, 3/4 + n/2] - PolyGamma[0, 3/4 + n/2])/4
```

The polygamma function of order 0 is the digamma function (often denoted $\psi(x)$), the logarithmic derivative of the gamma function. Mathematica will also give you the limit

```
Limit[(PolyGamma[0, 3/4 + n/2] - PolyGamma[0, 3/4 + n/2])/4,n->Infinity] = 0
```

This can be shown from the fact that $\psi(x) = \ln(x) + O(x^{-1})$, and so
$$
\frac{1}{4}\left[\psi\left(\frac{n}{2} + \frac{3}{4}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{n}{2} + \frac{3}{4}\right)\right] = \frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left(1 + \frac{2}{2n+1}\right) + O(n^{-1})\right] = O(n^{-1})
$$
Which goes to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer my question... I know how to solve it, but i need to solve with Mathematica: that's the requirement

Comment: @DenisGantsev You're going to need to be more clear with your goal here. As you can see, Mathematica is capable of evaluating the integral and giving its limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$. What more do you want it to do?

Answer (score 1):

One can calculate the integral directly:

$$\begin{align}I_n&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^{2n}(x)~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^{2(n-1)}(x)\sec^2(x)-\tan^{2(n-1)}(x)~\mathrm dx\\&=\frac1{2n-1}\tan^{2n-1}(x)\bigg|_0^{\pi/4}-I_{n-1}\\&=\frac1{2n-1}-I_{n-1}\end{align}$$

Thus,

> $$\begin{align}I_n&=\frac1{2n-1}-I_{n-1}\\&=\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n-3}+I_{n-2}\\&=\dots\\&=(-1)^nI_0+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{2k-1}\\&=(-1)^n\frac\pi4+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{2k-1}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer my question... I know how to solve it, but i need to solve with Mathematica: that's the requirement

Comment: @DenisGantsev Oh!  My bad, I'm not really tech savvy.  Hope someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Digamma Function**

Letting $u=\tan x$ can transforms the integral into a power series as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan ^{2 n} x d x = & \int_0^1 \frac{u^{2 n}}{1+u^2} d u \\
= & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \int_0^1 u^{2 n+2 k} d u \\
= & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2 n+2 k+1} \\
= & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2 n+4 k+1}-\frac{1}{2 n+4 k+3}\right)\\= &\frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k+\frac{2 n+1}{4}}-\frac{1}{k+\frac{2 n+3}{4}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Recall the series representation of the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) , for any $k\ne0,-1,-2,…,$
$$
\psi(z)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+z}\right),
$$

by which we have

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan ^{2 n} x d x& =\frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+\frac{2 n+3}{4}}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+\frac{2 n+1}{4}}\right)\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{4}\left[\left(\psi\left(\frac{2 n+3}{4} + \gamma\right)\right)-\left(\psi\left(\frac{2 n+1}{4}+ \gamma\right)\right)\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{4}\left[\psi\left(\frac{2 n+3}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{2 n+1}{4}\right)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$